# over 100 soundcloud iframe widgets loading on page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to load over 100 souncloud iframe widgets however It takes almost 2 minutes to load all of the iframes. Here is the script code:

```
for (x in djlist) {
SC.get('/users/' + djlist[x] + '/tracks',{ limit: 1 }, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks[0].id);
   myTrack = tracks[0].id;
  var str = '<iframe width="500" height="20" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/' + myTrack + '&amp;color=0066cc&amp;inverse=true&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_user=true"></iframe>';
  var div = document.getElementById("body");
  div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );

   looper++;
});
}
```

I was thinking of maybe doing server-side rendering of the iframe objects first? I know each iframe makes an api reuqest to soundcloud to get the music. Am I being throttled?
Anyway to solve this?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that you load 100 at once? What about some sort of lazy load or user requested load? Check your dev tools and you can see where the bottleneck occurs.

Comment: no it is not neccessary but is there anyway to preload all of the iframes on the server? so it only makes an api request to soundcloud when they push the play button the iframe widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you should create your own interface with a play button and switch by the correct iframe when user click it. To play automatically you should set autoplay parameter to true. See below:

HTML:

```
<div class="myPlayer">
    <span id="trackName">My Music</span> 
    <button id="playButton" data-track="72395994">Play</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var iframeStart = '<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/';
var iframeEnd = '&amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>});';

$("#playButton").click(function(){
    var iframeCode = iframeStart + $(this).attr("data-track") + iframeEnd;
    $(".myPlayer").html(iframeCode);
});
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/x702rfxv/2/